# Como mudar o path do PostBackUrl de um asp.Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho a seguinte situação: na minha página .aspx eu tenho um asp.Button que, após rodar um evento OnClick no behind, executa um PostBackUrl para outra página levando informações através de HiddenFields.

O que eu estou tentando fazer é: ao tentar cadastrar um cliente, caso o email inserido já esteja cadastrado no banco, o botão não execute o PostBackUrl ou mude a sua URL para que página não mude. Caso contrário, execute normalmente e prossiga para o perfil.

O meu botão no front :

```html
<asp:Button ID="continuebtn" OnClick="Continuebtn_Click" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/cliente/perfil.aspx" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" Text="Continuar"/>
```

E o código behind está assim (resumidamente) :

```cs
protected void Continuebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
    {
        try
        {
            string consulta = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente WHERE Email = @email"
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conn);
            cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@email",clienteEmail);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader.Read())//caso exista um cliente cadastrado com o email inserido
                //altera o PostBackUrl para se manter na mesma página
            else//se o email inserido for novo
                //mantém o PostBackUrl do botão
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            EscreveLog(ex.Message);
        }
        finnaly
        {
            conn.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Até o momento eu já tentei :

```cs
continuebtn.PostBackUrl = "";

continuebtn.Attributes["PostBackUrl"] = "return false";

continuebtn.Attributes.Remove("OnClick");
continuebtn.Attributes.Add("OnClick","return false");

continuebtn.OnClientClick = "return false;";

colocar só um return no else
```

E nenhuma alternativa deu certo, todos continuam a executar o PostBack com a url "~/cliente/perfil.aspx"

Espero que eu tenha sido claro na explicação, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Qualquer componente de validação faz isso para você, só esse trecho de código não tem como ajudar, poderia colocar um exemplo minimo?

Comment: Alterei o código behind.

Comment: eu acho que você está fazendo errado.

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico?

Comment: você mexe com aspnet forms se você validar a tela não precisa fazer nada no botão.

Comment: Creio que você não entendeu o que eu estou perguntando.

Comment: Creio que você não sabe o que está fazendo, a diferença está ai: eu sei fazer o que você quer fazer, só validar a tela com o componente de validação.

Comment: primeira coisa: conte o que está fazendo? não pergunte somente como, mas, o que você pretende?

Comment: Está no segundo paragrafo, editei para melhor compreensao.

Comment: Você clica no botão: e o mesmo verifica se existe ou não o e-mail, se não existir ele prossegue para outra página? (se não volta/permanece na mesma?)?

Comment: Isso, se ja existir eu quero que a aplicacao se mantenha na mesma página, ignorando o PostBackUrl do botão.

Comment: você quer um processo assíncrono, e na verdade uma validação assincrona

Comment: você pode fazer assim: clica no botão no código verifica o email se sim da um redirect se não envia uma mensagem e remova esse endereço dai e coloque no código `PostBackUrl="~/cliente/perfil.aspx" `

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119897/discussion-between-fabio-hagiwara-and-novic).

Comment: Depois de muito tempo pesquisando um usuário do StackOverflow em Inglês respondeu meu post lá. Não é possível mudar o path do PostBackUrl depois que o botão for clicado, sua propriedade só muda depois do postback automatico do asp.Button. A saída que me foi recomendada é de usar o Server.Transfer, que também mantém as informações como um cross-page normal.

Comment: Ueh mas, eu disse isso para você Fabio